# Comparing number with varchar2

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this function and I need to compare number with varchar.

```
      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getOdds(i_odd in varchar2, i_id in number) return number as
begin
declare odd integer;
declare i_perecentage=0;
begin

if i_odd ='SP'
then
return (0);
end if;

odd:=round(to_number((1-i_perecentage/100)*i_odd),2);
  if odd<1 
  then          
 return(i_odd);
 else
 return(round(odd,2));
 end if;

end;
end;
/
```

PS: I edited function and i resolve problem with comparing , now i have another situation that i dont like..
This function returns calculated percentage of i_odd. The problem is that if i pass 0 in i_percentage in results i get result with no decimal places(for example: i_odd = 3.10 and i_percentage = 0 i get odd = 3 but if I pass i_odd = 3.10 and i_percentage = 1 i get odd = 3.10 ). 
Why is on i_percentage = 0 i dont get decimal places ??

Comment: How can a numeric value be equal to 'SP'?

Comment: This i_odd is in 99% number but there is possibility that it can be SP in rare cases so i have to eliminate with this if...

Comment: @civesuas_sine: i_odd is a `number`. It's can't be a string.

Comment: So i have to change i_number to varchar ?

Comment: The problem occurs before you compare anything. It's obviously impossible to pass a string like 'SP' into a function that only accepts numbers. You'll need to either change the parameter to allow strings, or change something in the calling process so the issue doesn't arise, or else rethink whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: By the way the standard place to declare variables is in the implicit `declare` section just before the first `begin`. You don't need to start a whole new nested block with its own `declare` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getOdds(i_odd in varchar2, i_id in number) return varchar2 as

odd varchar2(10);
ret_value number(4); 

begin

if (i_odd ='SP') or i_odd is null then 
return 'SP';
else
  odd :=ROUND( TO_NUMBER( ( 1 - (play_beting.get_odds_percentage(i_id) / 100 ) ) * TO_NUMBER(i_odd) ), 2);  

   IF(odd < 1) THEN  
            ret_value := TO_NUMBER(i_odd);  
          ELSE  
            ret_value := to_char(odd,'9999.00');  
          END IF;  

      END IF;  

      RETURN to_char(ret_value,'9999.00');  

END getOdds;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to **validate** a varchar2 field as a number in PL/SQL, typically you'd just try converting it to a number and catch the exception.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getOdds(i_odd in varchar2, i_id in number) return number as
    odd number;
BEGIN
    -- if i_odd = 'SP' (or another non-number), this will throw an ORA-01722 
    -- exception which will be caught in the exception block, below
    odd := to_number(i_odd); -- you might want a format mask here

    --... now you can use "odd" as a number

EXCEPTION WHEN INVALID_NUMBER THEN
    return 0;
END;
/
```

You can also nest a begin..end block in the middle of your code just to catch exceptions, if that works better for you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getOdds(i_odd in varchar2, i_id in number) return number as
    odd number;
begin

    begin
      odd := to_number(i_odd); -- you might want a format mask here
    exception when INVALID_NUMBER then
      odd := 0;
    end;

    --... now you can use "odd" as a number

end;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you can't catch the invalid_number exception is because you are declaring the input parameter as a number.  When you call your function, Oracle tries to convert the string to a number first (and it fails of course, *before entering your code at all*).

If you change the input parameter to varchar2, then the conversions to number (implicit in this case) is done inside the function, and invalid numbers can be caught and handled as you want (here I'm just returning a different string to denote the issue):

```
create or replace function is_odd_even(i_num in varchar2)
return varchar2
is
begin
  -- conversion to number is done here
  if (mod(i_num, 2) = 0) then
    return 'EVEN';
  else
    return 'ODD';
  end if;

exception
  when INVALID_NUMBER or VALUE_ERROR then
    -- do something meaningful
    return 'INV';
end;
```

Usage example:

```
with x as (
  select '1' as val from dual
  union all
  select 'SP' as val from dual
  union all
  select '2' as val from dual
)
select x.val, is_odd_even(x.val)
from x;
```

Output:

```
1   ODD
SP  INV
2   EVEN
```